# Int64Index object has no attribute get_values

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am doing the following manual: https://towardsdatascience.com/mapping-geograph-data-in-python-610a963d2d7f

I'm getting the following error from this code:

```
# Plot Comuna
comuna = 'SANTIAGO'
com_id = df[df.NOM_COMUNA == comuna].index.get_values()[0]
plot_shape(com_id, comuna)
```

Error

**AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'get_values'**

Comment: it's just `df['tableName'].values`
`df['tableName'].index` gets all the indices, not the value of a given index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [to_numpy() because get_values is deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_values.html) as of pandas version 0.25.0.

Try:

```
comuna = 'SANTIAGO'
com_id = df[df.NOM_COMUNA == comuna].index.to_numpy()[0]
plot_shape(com_id, comuna)
```